# Can't access Dev Container(docker) with VS Code

Tags: docker, vscode-remote, vscode-devcontainer

Error running command remote-containers.attachToRunningContainerFromViewlet: Shell server terminated (code: 255, signal: null)
...

I was using it by attaching to docker container with vscode.
When I attach to the same container again after a few weeks without doing anything, the following error appears.
I tried changing the version of the extension's Dev Containers or reinstalling it, but to no avail.
In the last log, it says Permission denied (publickey,password). but I couldn't find any clue.
Is there anyone who can help?

Below is terminal log.

```
[78 ms] Dev Containers 0.266.1 in VS Code 1.71.2 (74b1f979648cc44d385a2286793c226e611f59e7).
[78 ms] Start: Resolving Remote
[79 ms] Setting up container: /ycool.kwon_test
[79 ms] Host: ssh://10.229.9.224
[83 ms] Start: Run: ssh 10.229.9.224 /bin/sh
[156 ms] Start: Run in host: id -un
[10633 ms] Shell server terminated (code: 255, signal: null)

XSL ���� �Ǵ� ���� �̸��� �߸��Ǿ����ϴ�.
node:child_process:925
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Command failed: wmic process where (commandline like "%ssh-askpass.bat%") get processid,parentprocessid /format:"%WINDIR%\System32\wbem\en-us\csv"
XSL ���� �Ǵ� ���� �̸��� �߸��Ǿ����ϴ�.

    at checkExecSyncError (node:child_process:848:11)
    at Object.execSync (node:child_process:922:15)
    at Object.<anonymous> (node:electron/js2c/asar_bundle:5:12704)
    at Object.<anonymous> (c:\Users\ycool.kwon.SECDS\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.266.1\dist\common\sshAskpass.js:5:808)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1165:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1220:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1035:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:876:12)
    at c._load (node:electron/js2c/asar_bundle:5:13343)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12) {
  status: 44210,
  signal: null,
  output: [
    null,
    Buffer(0) [Uint8Array] [],
    Buffer(44) [Uint8Array] [
       88,  83,  76,  32, 199, 252, 189, 196,  32,
      182, 199, 180, 194,  32, 198, 196, 192, 207,
       32, 192, 204, 184, 167, 192, 204,  32, 192,
      223, 184, 248, 181, 199, 190, 250, 189, 192,
      180, 207, 180, 217,  46,  13,  13,  10
    ]
  ],
  pid: 30544,
  stdout: Buffer(0) [Uint8Array] [],
  stderr: Buffer(44) [Uint8Array] [
     88,  83,  76,  32, 199, 252, 189, 196,  32,
    182, 199, 180, 194,  32, 198, 196, 192, 207,
     32, 192, 204, 184, 167, 192, 204,  32, 192,
    223, 184, 248, 181, 199, 190, 250, 189, 192,
    180, 207, 180, 217,  46,  13,  13,  10
  ]
}
Permission denied, please try again.
XSL ���� �Ǵ� ���� �̸��� �߸��Ǿ����ϴ�.
node:child_process:925
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Command failed: wmic process where (commandline like "%ssh-askpass.bat%") get processid,parentprocessid /format:"%WINDIR%\System32\wbem\en-us\csv"
XSL ���� �Ǵ� ���� �̸��� �߸��Ǿ����ϴ�.

    at checkExecSyncError (node:child_process:848:11)
    at Object.execSync (node:child_process:922:15)
    at Object.<anonymous> (node:electron/js2c/asar_bundle:5:12704)
    at Object.<anonymous> (c:\Users\ycool.kwon.SECDS\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.266.1\dist\common\sshAskpass.js:5:808)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1165:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1220:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1035:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:876:12)
    at c._load (node:electron/js2c/asar_bundle:5:13343)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12) {
  status: 44210,
  signal: null,
  output: [
    null,
    Buffer(0) [Uint8Array] [],
    Buffer(44) [Uint8Array] [
       88,  83,  76,  32, 199, 252, 189, 196,  32,
      182, 199, 180, 194,  32, 198, 196, 192, 207,
       32, 192, 204, 184, 167, 192, 204,  32, 192,
      223, 184, 248, 181, 199, 190, 250, 189, 192,
      180, 207, 180, 217,  46,  13,  13,  10
    ]
  ],
  pid: 17512,
  stdout: Buffer(0) [Uint8Array] [],
  stderr: Buffer(44) [Uint8Array] [
     88,  83,  76,  32, 199, 252, 189, 196,  32,
    182, 199, 180, 194,  32, 198, 196, 192, 207,
     32, 192, 204, 184, 167, 192, 204,  32, 192,
    223, 184, 248, 181, 199, 190, 250, 189, 192,
    180, 207, 180, 217,  46,  13,  13,  10
  ]
}
Permission denied, please try again.
XSL ���� �Ǵ� ���� �̸��� �߸��Ǿ����ϴ�.
node:child_process:925
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Command failed: wmic process where (commandline like "%ssh-askpass.bat%") get processid,parentprocessid /format:"%WINDIR%\System32\wbem\en-us\csv"
XSL ���� �Ǵ� ���� �̸��� �߸��Ǿ����ϴ�.

    at checkExecSyncError (node:child_process:848:11)
    at Object.execSync (node:child_process:922:15)
    at Object.<anonymous> (node:electron/js2c/asar_bundle:5:12704)
    at Object.<anonymous> (c:\Users\ycool.kwon.SECDS\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.266.1\dist\common\sshAskpass.js:5:808)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1165:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1220:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1035:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:876:12)
    at c._load (node:electron/js2c/asar_bundle:5:13343)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12) {
  status: 44210,
  signal: null,
  output: [
    null,
    Buffer(0) [Uint8Array] [],
    Buffer(44) [Uint8Array] [
       88,  83,  76,  32, 199, 252, 189, 196,  32,
      182, 199, 180, 194,  32, 198, 196, 192, 207,
       32, 192, 204, 184, 167, 192, 204,  32, 192,
      223, 184, 248, 181, 199, 190, 250, 189, 192,
      180, 207, 180, 217,  46,  13,  13,  10
    ]
  ],
  pid: 51760,
  stdout: Buffer(0) [Uint8Array] [],
  stderr: Buffer(44) [Uint8Array] [
     88,  83,  76,  32, 199, 252, 189, 196,  32,
    182, 199, 180, 194,  32, 198, 196, 192, 207,
     32, 192, 204, 184, 167, 192, 204,  32, 192,
    223, 184, 248, 181, 199, 190, 250, 189, 192,
    180, 207, 180, 217,  46,  13,  13,  10
  ]
}
ycool.kwon@10.229.9.224: Permission denied (publickey,password).
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was rsa authentication problem.
In Windows, I could access to server ssh by entering a password, but container attach seems to be inaccessible because there is no place to enter a password.

I added id_rsa, id_rsa.pub at C:\Users\ycool.kwon.SECDS.ssh at window side.
At C:\Users\ycool.kwon.SECDS.ssh\config, I added below for auto login.

```
  IdentityFile "~\\.ssh\\id_rsa"
  ForwardAgent yes
```

And I wrote id_rsa.pub in ~/.ssh/authorized_keys of server.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem, and the solution was to revert the Dev Containers extension in VS code to the older version (v0.309.0 in my case). The cause of the problem was a recent update of the extension. More information in this [github issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/9064#issuecomment-1747913455)